# Decomposing into BCNF

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Suppose R = {A,B,C,D}
And FD = C→D,C→A,B→C

I am supposed to find:
1. the key(s)
2. the NF it is in
3. the BCNF (if possible and if not in already)

So here's what I've got so far:

1. the key is B since it transitively determines C which determines D and A.
2. it is in 2NF since dependancies are on the whole key
3. R1 = {B,C} R2 = {C, A, D}

   - So here's where I have an issue. The mark scheme says to decompose R into AC, BC, and CD.  But why wouldn't my answer be right? Am I saying the FD is C -> {A,D} and if so is this difference to C -> A and C -> D?

Answer (score 0):

When you're asked to compute the minimum cover of R, you're usually expected to answer like this.

- C -> D
- C -> A
- B -> C

When you're asked to elevate R to BCNF, you're usually expected to answer like this.

- **B** C
- **C** AD

If you're not using a standard textbook, I can't give you any suggestions. Questions and answers written by TAs (teaching assistants) are particularly hard to understand. Sometimes they're just wrong.